# JS: need a css color code based on a string

Tags: javascript, css, string, random, colors

I need a function to generate a CSS color based on a string with a range of `min: #000000` and `max: #FFFFFF`. If the length or any of the characters in the input string changes, the function should return a different color (but it must always return the same color on the same string input).

For Example:

```
f("Reddit") ==>#FF0000

f("Smith") ==>#FFC0CB   

f("Smixh")==>#F008FF

f("Smith") ==>#FFC0CB

f("foo")==>#FF00FF

f("Reddit") ==>#FF0000
```

And so on. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: this depends COMPLETELY on what kind of qualities of the string that you want to affect the colour. ex. length of string means darker colour.

Comment: Are color dupes for different strings okay? Unique strings are impossible to guarantee without some rules governing the strings themselves. What's minimum/maximum characters for instance?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd [hash the string](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5) and use the first six characters of the hex checksum as your hex color code:

```
function color(string) {
    return '#' + md5(string).slice(0, 6);
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4PMnA/48/**

Comment: CRC32 might be a better (faster) option than MD5.

Comment: jsfiddle demo did not work anymore (problem loading md5 lib). Fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/4PMnA/48/